# htaccess redirect prefix to a domain

Tags: .htaccess, web, redirect

I made a website with 2 langages. I have a specific domain for each one. I bought them and they point to the same directory (so they display the same site).

I'd love to redirect each langage to its specific domain.

I tried that :

```
RewriteRule ^fr/(.*)$ https://www.french-domain.com/fr/$1 [L,R=301]
```

`RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ https://www.english-domain.com/en/$1 [L,R=301]`

But it creates an error with loop.

Anyone have an idea ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you are always search for pattern that exists both in the old url and in the new url, and since they all points to the same folder... you entering to endless loop.

if you have 2 domains, so you can check by the domain itself,

like that:

```
HTTP_HOST fr.french-domain.com/(.*)
RewriteRule ^fr.french-domain.com/(.*)$ https://www.french-domain.com/fr/$1 [L,R=301]
```

i don't understand exactly hoe the domains looks like and to redirect to what, so maybe you will need to change it little bit.

but try this and update if it's working for you,

Answer (score 0):

You are not using correct rules to redirect your domains. Your rules only redirect Url path starting with `fr` and `en` ie: `example.com/fr` . To redirect domains to specific folders , first of all you need to check the `HTTP_HOST` header and then redirect that host to the folder .

Use the following rule in the directory/.htaccess   your domains are pointing to:

```
RewriteEngine on

# map fr-example.com to /fr-folder
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?fr-example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /fr-folder%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
# map eng-example.com to /eng-folder
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?eng-example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /eng-folder%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```